# How to add data to firestore document after creating user

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I have a react application that should sign up a user and add the user's info to a collection using the uid. I am using redux and have broken my code into component, reducer and action. This is the add user component:

```
state = {
    name : '',
    email : '',
    password : '',
    position : '',
    department : '',

}

handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.signUp(this.state)
}

render() {
   return(//I have my input fields and submit button here)
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        auth: state.firebase.auth
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        signUp: (newUser) => dispatch(signUp(newUser))
    }
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddUser);
```

I do my auth action in the authAction with:

```
export const signUp = (newUser) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore}) => {
        const firebase = getFirebase();
        const firestore = getFirestore();

        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            newUser.email,
            newUser.password
        ).then((resp) =>{
            return firestore.collection('users').doc(resp.user.uid).set({
                name: newUser.name,
                position: newUser.position,
                department: newUser.department
            })
        }).then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'SIGNUP_SUCCESS' })
        }).catch(err => {
            dispatch({ type: 'SIGNUP_ERROR', err})
        })
    }
}
```

my Sign Up reducer is:

```
    case 'SIGNUP_SUCCESS':
        console.log('Signup success');
        return {
            ...state,
            authError: null
        }
    case 'SIGNUP_ERROR': 
    console.log('signup error');
    return {
        ...state,
        authError: action.err.message
    }
```

The issue is that this creates a user and logs the user in but doesn't create a document with the user data in the firestore collection. I do not get any errors on the console. it also doesn't log the success message. The user is created and can log in though.
What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does it do, if not what you expect? Please edit the question to explain what you observe as part of debugging.  If there is an error message, show it.

Comment: Edited. what it does so far is sign up the user. I expect it to set other user info to firestore using the uid acquired after creating the user. There are no error messages

Comment: I copied your code and ran it in a simple react App (without Redux) and it worked as expected. I am led to think that for some reason in your environment, the code within the first `.then()` and after, is not executing. Could you put a console log right before the Firestore user creation to confirm this?

Comment: It works well even if I do it with simple JavaScript. With the react/redux, I tried a different Firebase function to create a firestore collection and attached a .then(), they both executed. seems like the problem is only with createUserWithEmailAndPassword() every function that goes after that doesnt run

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand right that it is an async process? If yes, you should also use Redux-Saga library for this(I mean it would be better practice).
However, if you are not willing to implement that try adding debugger or console log data in sign up action before return to see if you passing the right data in the right format for firebase. Same goes to catch block, console log error, I may say useful information if the error is in request/response.

Comment: When I do a console log before setting data to firestore, it logs and prints the success message. but that's as far as it goes.